# Replacing two rows violating two different constraints with `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE`

Tags: postgresql

Assume we have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ctest (
    ID INTEGER,
    Value TEXT,
    Age INTEGER,
    Weight INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID, Value), UNIQUE (Age, Weight));
```

and we have a couple of rows there already:

```
INSERT INTO ctest (ID, Value, Age, Weight) VALUES (0, 'second', 1, 2);
INSERT INTO ctest (ID, Value, Age, Weight) VALUES (0, 'first', 1, 3);
```

Suppose we now want to insert a row that violates both the `primary key` and the `unique` constraints:

```
INSERT INTO ctest (ID, Value, Age, Weight) VALUES (0, 'second', 1, 3)
    ON CONFLICT (ID, Value, Weight, Age) DO UPDATE SET
        ID = EXCLUDED.ID,
        Value = EXCLUDED.Value,
        Age = EXCLUDED.Age,
        Weight = EXCLUDED.Weight;
```

Nope, that doesn't work: we get `no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT`.

If, when creating the `ctest` table, we also add an `UNIQUE (ID, Value, Age, Weight)` constraint (as some research suggests this might help), that doesn't work either, but we get a different sort of error: this time it's about `ctest_pkey` being violated and key `(id, value)=(0, second)` already existing.

So, what's the right way to define the schema and spell out the `insert` statement so that both rows get replaced by a single new one?

Comment: which row do you expect to delete using this statement?

Comment: Both `(0, 'second', 1, 2)` and `(0, 'first', 1, 3)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INSERT statements cannot delete on conflict.

To delete existing rows based on come condition, use a `WITH ... DELETE ... RETURNING` construct.

```
WITH del AS (DELETE FROM ctest 
             WHERE (Age=1 AND Weight=3)
                OR (ID = 0 AND Value = 'second')
             RETURNING 0, 'second', 1, 3
            )
INSERT INTO ctest (ID, Value, Age, Weight)
SELECT * 
FROM  del
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
```

Comment: Ah, that's a pity. I was hoping for SQLite-like behaviour so that the ORM library I'm doing would handle things like this uniformly, but probably this is not worth the effort. Thanks for your reply!